# Return accesstoken after Oauth Authentication in passport.js

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-twitter

I want the following flow in my app

1. User selects authenticate with google
2. I redirect to google and get the callback (This happens using Passport)

I now want to return an auth token that is specific to my application in the form of response to user.

```
  var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // RETURN ACCESS  TOKEN IN THE RESPONSE
  }
));
```

I do get the success callback, but I don know how to return a custom access token/response from the callback function.

I guess the answer related to using of done(), or serialization or deserialization which I am not clear from the docs or any examples. Can you please also explain how  done(), or serialization or deserialization are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in serialization and deserialization. See this [passport example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/85845d8d932d2f2dcd78093487af042f69c11258/examples/express3-mongoose-rememberme/app.js)

```
userSchema.methods.generateRandomToken = function () {
  var user = this,
    chars = "_!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890",
    token = new Date().getTime() + '_';

  for ( var x = 0; x < 16; x++ ) {
    var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 62 );
    token += chars.charAt( i );
  }
  return token;
};

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

//serialize
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done){
        var createAccessToken = function() {
            var token = user.generateRandomToken()
            User.findOne({
                accessToken: token
            }, function(err, existingUser){
                if (err) { return done(err) }
                if (existingUser) {
                    createAccessToken()
                } else {
                    user.set('accessToken', token)
                    user.save(function(err){
                        if (err) { return done(err) }
                        return done(null, user.get('accessToken'))
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        if (user._id) {
            createAccessToken()
        }
    })


//deserialize
passport.deserializeUser(function(token, done){
        User.findOne({
            accessToken : token
        }, function(err, user){
            done(err, user)
        })
    })
```